# how to add hover effects to bootstrap navigation menu

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

Hi guys i am new to web development and i am trying to add a hover effect to my nav menu , something like the first example in this link : https://codepen.io/Calloumi/pen/vndlH

I tried to implement the same idea to my bootstrap html nav menu , however mine behaves slightly in different way, only the bottom border seems to move inwards and when i hover over the Links and hovering over them also moves my menu item up. i am not sure what need to add/ change to make it work the same way

```css
.navbar-light .navbar-nav .nav-link {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 13px;
  text-decoration: none;
  background: white;
  color: black;
  font-family: "open-sans";
  transition: 0.3s ease;
  border-top: 4px solid #FFFFFF;
  border-bottom: 4px solid #FFFFFF;
  padding: 20px 0;
  margin: 0 20px;
}

.navbar-light .navbar-nav .nav-link.active,
.navbar-light .navbar-nav .nav-link:hover {
  border-top: 4px solid #000000;
  border-bottom: 4px solid #000000;
  padding: 6px 0px;
  background: #11ADE8;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.6/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-wHAiFfRlMFy6i5SRaxvfOCifBUQy1xHdJ/yoi7FRNXMRBu5WHdZYu1hA6ZOblgut" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-B0UglyR+jN6CkvvICOB2joaf5I4l3gm9GU6Hc1og6Ls7i6U/mkkaduKaBhlAXv9k" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<nav class="navbar fixed-top navbar-expand-md navbar-light ">

  <div class="container-fluid">

    <a class="navbar-brand " href="#">
      <img src="images/logoblue.png" alt="">
    </a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler first-button darken-3" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarResponsive" aria-controls="navbarResponsive" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
       <div class="animated-icon1"><span></span><span></span><span></span></div>
        </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarResponsive">
      <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
        <li class="nav-item active">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Services</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Products</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Booking</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Prices</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Gallery</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Contact us</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
</nav>
```

Any help is much appreciated towards achieving the same hover effect to my navigation menu.

Answer (score 3):

You have an insane amount of HTML for a simple navigation. The codepen you linked does it correctly. A set of links (i.e. anchor tags) wrapped in a nav element.

The correct solution here is to simplify your HTML.

```css
nav {
  margin-top: 40px;
  padding: 24px;
  text-align: center;
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  background: #3fa46a;
}

nav a {
  transition: 0.3s ease;
  background: #3fa46a;
  color: white;
  font-size: 20px;
  text-decoration: none;
  border-top: 4px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 4px solid transparent;
  padding: 20px 0;
  margin: 0 5px;
  font-size: 17px;
}
nav a:hover {
  border-top: 4px solid white;
  border-bottom: 4px solid white;
  padding: 6px 0; 
}
```

```html
<nav>
    <a href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
    <a href="#">Services</a>
    <a href="#">Products</a>
    <a href="#">Booking</a>
    <a href="#">Prices</a>
    <a href="#">Gallery</a>
    <a href="#">Contact us</a>
</nav>
```

Comment: as stated , i am using Bootstrap Navbar templates . and trying to achieve the same hovering effect . i could have simply do what you did , but that is not what i wanted. i am attempting to achieve the same result but for the Bootstrap Navbar template that i have.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: you need to remove the `.navbar-light` class from the `:hover` styling and use `display:inline` for the `navbar-nav` it will work as intended. Below is corrected code from your codepen in the comments.

```
 .navbar-light .navbar-nav .nav-link {
    display: inline;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 13px;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: black;
    font-family:"open-sans";
    transition: 0.3s ease;
    border-top: 4px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 4px solid transparent;
    margin: 0 20px;
    padding: 20px 0;

}

 .navbar-nav .nav-link.active,
 .navbar-nav .nav-link:hover {
    border-top: 4px solid #000000;
    border-bottom: 4px solid #000000;
    background:#11ADE8;
    padding: 6px 0;
}
```

Comment: @cd64 can you check whats wrong with my css approach?  it kind of does the job , only the bottom boarder seem to move inwards but the menu seems to move up too. thanks

Comment: use `display:inline;`  for your `.navbar-light .navbar-nav .nav-link`  styling.

Comment: display:inline; seems to help , However when you adjust the screen size for smaller devices , it messes up the links in the menu.

Comment: Unfortunately the code you posted works on all window sizes for me (it should collapse with navbar collapse and it doesn't which means you have extra code or aren't setting up the bootstrap nav correctly). I would check your other stylings and possible divs, two of your html divs `<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarResponsive">` and `<div class="container-fluid">` don't have closing </div> tags, theres also no <header> or <body>  so I would maybe start there or post the rest of your code

Comment: it works on all window sizes , but when it collapses and i click the hamburger menu to open the menus , the links are getting close to each other , and you see the white border lines under it. I only posted the snippet of the html and css code to do with the nav bar , my whole project does include all those. but there is no option for me to upload the whole project folder here here. i can send it to you to check it if it is possible ?

Comment: https://codepen.io/charly2019/pen/WPdbvJ    here is the link of my website , can you please check why my navigation behaves like that. @cb64 . thanks

Comment: I edited my answer, you need to remove `.navbar-light` from the hover style. Please mark the answer as accepted if it is working as intended. I would also personally recommend removing the bottom border from your `.navbar` class.

Comment: thanks for your feedback ,i have made those changes , but again ;  The problem is when i resize the window smaller , and i open the links from the toggle bar , the links all get close to each other and you see the white boarder lines , please check the link i gave you to inspect this yourself and what it looks like when you make the screen smaller. codepen.io/charly2019/pen/WPdbvJ   @cb64

Comment: @charly use `transparent` for the border top and bottom in your regular styles. I edited my answer again.

Comment: @charly last thing - I would also do something with that search bar, that seems to be the main issue with the nav alignment. Either make it a nav-item in the <ul> or move it to the top of the nav bar near the hamburger on mobile.

Comment: The transparency kinda patches that  hole , but the main problem is , when i use display:inline; for my regular styles , it moves the navbar to the left , when the screen is resized . even thought i have text-align: center;  , but when i have display:inline-block; instead , the links seem to appear in the center as it should do and also have spaces between them. the implementation doesn't seem to quite work as intended and messes up the navbar.  and for the Search bar , i completely remove it tested it , it doesn't cause any issue with the nav alignment.  so im well still confused . @cb64

Comment: Curious as to what benefit you’re getting from Bootstrap to outweigh headaches like this. Yes you can use 30 HTML elements do to do the job of 6 but …why? My understand is that bootstrap provides pre-baked styles for adhering to specific markup but you’re not even using bootstrap styling here.